# QGIS Text Italics parallel with longitude

Tags: qgis, labeling, text

I'd like to italicize text labels in QGIS such that each character's vertical lines are parallel to the longitudinal line in a Robinson projection. I can't find a good example of this online to demonstrate, but I'd like to make it look like the text is "on the ground" pointed to the north. I saw an answer that used Geometry Generator to calculate a virtual latitudinal line and place the text parallel to that, but I need the opposite and can't determine whether it's even possible with the labeling engine.